# Remove the resize animation on view visibility GONE

Tags: java, android

I am trying to simulate the iPhone X like navigation on Android using ViewPager. When the user releases the bar on the bottom, the viewpager's visibility is set to `View.GONE` and it shows the ugly drop down like animation as shown in the video https://youtu.be/k2EXKFulfzU.

I tried to remove the animation by directly changing the dimension of viewpager then changing it's visibility to GONE and it doesn't help. Thank you in advanced :)

```
FrameLayout ll = mLayout.findViewById(R.id.mainLL);
ll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, final MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    bar.animate().alpha(0.0f);
                    viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    layoutParams.height = old_y;
                    viewPager.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Animation a = new Animation() {
                        @Override
                        protected void applyTransformation(float factor, Transformation t) {

                            float factorX = (float)scaleX + factor;

                            int currentPos = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

                            if (currentPos != 0) {
                                adapter.getItem(currentPos - 1).setScaleX(Math.min(factorX, 1));
                                adapter.getItem(currentPos - 1).setScaleY(Math.min(factorX, 1));
                            }

                            adapter.getItem(currentPos).setScaleX(Math.min(factorX, 1));
                            adapter.getItem(currentPos).setScaleY(Math.min(factorX, 1));

                            adapter.getItem(currentPos + 1).setScaleX(Math.min(factorX, 1));
                            adapter.getItem(currentPos + 1).setScaleY(Math.min(factorX, 1));

                            if(adapter.getItem(currentPos).getScaleX() > 0.1) {
                                if(factor == 1){
                                    viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }


                        }


                    };

                    bar.animate().alpha(1.0f);
                    viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    a.setDuration(zoomInDuration);
                    viewPager.startAnimation(a);
                    break;
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/navigationLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.thanoscorp.uigestures.ViewPager.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/appViewpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/barLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/overlayBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:paddingLeft="100dp"
            android:paddingRight="100dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/bar"
            android:tint="#FF0000" />

    </LinearLayout>
    
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Post some code, hard to suggest a fix otherwise

Comment: @elmorabea updated with code

Comment: Try using withEndAction and in the action change the visibility of the item. Allow the animation to run then set the end visibility value with withEndAction or withStartAction

Comment: I think what you have said is similar to what I have done in the function `applyTransformation`  when the interpolatedTime i.e., factor reaches it's maximum value of 1, the visibility is being set to GONE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get rid of the animation, instead, i created another layout and added it to the window manager using `wm.addView(vpLayout, lp);` and removed it using `wm.removeView(vpLayout);`

and in case you are wondering what `vpLayout` is, I have seperated the ViewPager into another layout file and inflated it into a `FrameLayout` whose name is `vpLayout`. It took a while and it was worth it, but it gave birth to a new problem. Hope I will solve it too. Thanks :)